# How to print sequence of characters according to the number next to it?

Tags: java, string, character, sequence

**Input: a2b4c3

Output: aabbbbccc**

**Here is my code**.........which has wrong output:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class hi
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String a="a2b4c3";
String alpha="";
ArrayList<Character> num=new ArrayList<Character>();
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
{
  char c=a.charAt(i);
  if(Character.isDigit(c)==true)
   {
     num.add(c);
   }
  else
   {
    alpha+=c;
   }
}
for(int y=0; y<num.size(); y++)
 {
   for(int z=0; z<num.get(y); z++)
    { 
      System.out.print(alpha.charAt(y));
    }
  }
}
}
```

Whats wrong in this code, I didn't get the output as expected

**My output is**: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

**Need corrections or code in java**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Here your answer.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Hi
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a="a2b4c3";
        String alpha="";
        ArrayList<Character> num=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            char c=a.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c)==true)
            {
                num.add(c);
            }
            else
            {
                alpha+=c;
            }
        }
        for(int y=0; y<num.size(); y++)
        {
            int count=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num.get(y)));

            for(int z=0; z<count; z++)
            {
                System.out.print(alpha.charAt(y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or

import java.lang.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

```
class Hi
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a="a2b4c3";
        String alpha="";
        ArrayList<Integer> num=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            char c=a.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c)==true)
            {
                num.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c)));
            }
            else
            {
                alpha+=c;
            }
        }
        for(int y=0; y<num.size(); y++)
        {
            for(int z=0; z<num.get(y); z++)
            {
                System.out.print(alpha.charAt(y));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for` loop as this:

```
for(int y=0; y<num.size(); y++)
 {
    for(int z=0; z<Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num.get(y))); z++)
      {
        System.out.print(alpha.charAt(y));
      }
 }
```

Or better try this approach:

```
class hi
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a="a2b4c3";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length()-1;i=i+2)
        {
            int value=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(i+1)));
            for (int j=0;j<value;j++){
                stringBuilder.append(a.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `'2'` has the integer value `50`, see http://www.asciitable.com/ . That is why you get 50 * a printed.

Solution: subtract `'0'` (which has value `48`), e.g. before adding it to the list: `num.add(c - '0');`. Not necessary but makes the intention cleaner: you should then change `num` to be an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead.

Comment: I didn't  think of this.........thanks bro........nw i got where i was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String input = "a2b4c3";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?i)([a-z])(\\d+)");
String output = pat.matcher(input).replaceAll(m -> m.group(1).repeat(Integer.valueOf(m.group(2))));
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider this?

```
String input = "a2b4c3";

for(String group : input.split("(?<=\\d++)")) {          
   System.out.print(group.substring(0,1).repeat(Integer.parseInt(group.substring(1))));
}
```

prints

```
aabbbbccc
```

It works as follows:

- `(?<=\\d++)` says split at locations following a group of digits
- then just use `substring` combined with the `repeat` method to process the character and convert the number to an `int` to print the result.